# Mixing gtk+ and c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk

Is there any reason to use special bindings when using c++ to program in gtk+?  Being that c++ is a superset of C, why can't a class with static members for the call back events be used and the c style gtk+ object be encapsulated in a class as such:

```
class MainWindow{
    public:
         MainWindow(void);
         GtkWidget* window;
         GtkWidget* button;
         static void signals(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer callback_data);
         static gboolean onDelete(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data);
         static void onDestroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data);
         /* GtkWidget* canvas;
         GtkWidget* items; */

     };
```

and signal connections done at construction:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(){
// Create widgets
        window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Push the button.");
// Connect widget signals
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(signals), NULL);
// Add widgets to main window (pack multiple widgets)
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
// Show window
        gtk_widget_show_all(window);
// Connect Main Window Signals
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(onDelete), NULL);
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(onDestroy), NULL);
```

}

Then just create the class in Main after setting up the gtk+ calls:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
      {

    // initialize GTK
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        gdk_rgb_init();
    // Create Main Window...
        MainWindow win;
    // Listen
        gtk_main();
        return 0;
      }
```

The constructor can take parameters for initial size and position and what ever other options...

Am I making this too easy or is all the other stuff I have read making it too hard?

Comment: Of course you can use the C bindings. The point of C++ bindings like gtkmm is that they are likely to integrate better into C++ programs.

Comment: You have to watch object lifetimes more to avoid memory leaks, and there's less type safety so expect more runtime errors. Also there's more boilerplate, so the code will be less readable.  But technically it can work fine, although I'd never recommend it.

Answer (score 6):

You may do that.

GTK also already has been given a C++ wrapper, if you like C++ interfaces.

It's called [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/documentation.html).

Comment: You can also access the C object directly by using the `->gobj()` member of a Gtk C++ class object. And in that way use the C API intermixed with the C++ wrapper (https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-gobj-and-wrap.html.en).

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do that. But due to many pre-defined classes programming with gtkmm adds more object oriented enviroment which will reduce useless code.